# Batch Random Variable Name

Tags: batch-file, variables, random

```
set %random% randomfolder=
md %randomfolder%
cd %randomfolder%
pause
```

Now when I run this command as .bat file it gives this error:

> C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\Folderspammer>set 23191 randomfolder=
>
> C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\Folderspammer>md
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\Folderspammer>cd
>
> C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\Folderspammer
>
> C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\Folderspammer>pause
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: as you are clearly new to batch scripting, I suggest using the `/?` switch for commands you are experiencing issues and reading the associated help output. This question results from a syntax error which you should have rather easily been able to solve had you done any level of research prior to asking this off topic question

Comment: I would absolutely love to know the reason for this. You do realize that `%random%` can never be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to use a random value for that directory name, the first line should be:

```
set randomfolder=%random%
```

And, once you finish debugging, you may want to put this before your first line so it doesn't clog up your output with the lines being executed.:

```
@echo off
```

Comment: I didn't use @echo off bc i was using the least lines possible + why does this code works this way if this code works like this :
```
set /p randomfolder=

Comment: @Quidney: that's because `set /p` is to get user to enter value. In that case, the thing after the `=` is the prompt to use, as in `set /p val=What?` If you're not using `/p`, it's simpy `set varname=value`.